# Using AdMob for own ads (in-house) in own application, how?

Tags: android, ios, admob, ads

### The problem

A client wants to use AdMob to print his own *in-house* ads in his own application. He wants to monetize the app through his own sponsors, hence he creates the necessary ads himself and shows them on the app in native ads.

At first we tried to implement our own advertisement system but the app was rejected by Google.

So my former manager (*before being fired for incompetence*) sold to the client an AdMob account and training (?) by Google (*whatever that means*). I had to take over recently after having implemented the native ad into the application.

### The actual setup

In AdMob I have created the following campaign:
[image: Active AdMob Campaign]
with the following goal (manual eCPM):
[image: Settings for the campaign]

I have the following Mediation group created:
[image: Mediation group]
with the following settings:
[image]

### State of things

Still all I see are ads from the AdMob Network. I can't publish the app on a large scale yet because of the missing in-house ads.

What am I doing wrong? I've seen unfortunately few tutorials on the subject and over all they contradictory on the eCPM values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes you can.it's called house ads in admob.It shows when there is no impression in admob ad.

Comment: @shakac but how do I force the house ads to be shown?

Comment: please refer to this link [https://support.google.com/admob/thread/7007472?hl=en]

Comment: @shakac I know this thread all to good, every time I find only this one, but all answers are the same: have you found a solution? So no good, that's why I'm here.

Comment: i never tried but you can talk to admob help center.they must help

Comment: There's no help center to either call or contact anyone at Google, it's only the FAQ / documentation (or I missed something).

Comment: ok i found a way to show house ads 100%.What you can do is ad a floor CPM of admob to 10000$ that is impossible to fill by admob and your house ads CPM is 0.10$ so they will fill your house ads 100%.you can learn more about here https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9686161?hl=en&visit_id=637213434204228587-744507195&rd=1

Comment: @shakac I'm testing your suggestions (and thanks for the link, finally the right informations) and come back when the new campaign has started (tomorrow).

Comment: Welcome my friend.If you need any help about android,java don't hesitate to ask.I will try my best to give you proper solution.

Comment: @shakac still nothing, I updated the question though with screenshot, maybe you see a mistake I made?

Comment: where you tested it ? how many device have yo tested ?

Comment: Well there not so many terminals available because as long as it doesn't work I can't deploy on a large scale